# Reporting a grievance about a moderator

Tags: support, moderation

A moderator does not appear to be following the TOS. Where is the complaint form? What is the procedure?

Comment: If you have a complaint, use the [Contact Us](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/contact) form.  Just be aware that action would only be taken if *actual* rules are being violated in the [moderator agreement](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/legal/moderator-agreement) (which isn't really happening here).

Comment: Care to elaborate a bit? I'm sure we can sort this out - our moderators are pro-tem (appointed, not elected), but they've been doing a Hellovanawesome™ job moderating this site.

Comment: Presumably related to [this question](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/92086/optimization-of-matrix-and-loops).

Comment: What is TOS?...

Comment: @CoolGuy TOS = "Terms of Service". Agreement for using something, pretty much.

Answer (score 15):

As already mentioned by @Jamal in the comments, StackExchange provides a [Contact Form](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/contact), as well as an Inbox shared by the community managers.

That being said, namecalling is not really liked in such cases. If you wish to raise a complaint against moderators (who are **the** trusted authority in the whole network), please consider carefully whether you might be in the wrong.

You may also want to present your evidence in a calm and collected fashion. In general it's not a good idea to take aggressive stances "publicly", because you may experience a huge backlash.

For more information about moderators and their responsibilities, please refer to:

- The [moderator agreement](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/legal/moderator-agreement)
- The StackExchange ["Theory of Moderation"](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/)

For the officially documented steps to take when you think a moderator has abused their privileges, please refer to:

[What recourse do I have if I believe a moderator has abused his/her privileges?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/28867/222299)

Comment: @GAlexander I'm one of the Community Managers with Stack Exchange (i.e. a paid employee of the company that operates this site) and yes, contacting us on the team as described here is the way to go if you think a moderator has done something wrong. We'd always rather be called and not needed than needed and not called.